# Change voicemail message to audio file

Tags: settings, voicemail, setup

I have just got an iPhone and would like to change the voice message that people hear when I don't answer their calls.

Is there a way how I can setup the voice message to an audio file I have? I would like to do this because I have one of the funny ones you here time to time.

Also is there a maximum time limit for this?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question regarding changing your voicemail greeting, you're carrier network may have a different number to access your voicemails. By calling the voicemail number, you should be able to change this to what you want.

As for your second question, a solution could be play the audio file whilst your changing it from calling the voicemail number itself.

Again, depending on what carrier you use, they may set different time limits for voicemail greetings. For example Virgin Mobile from where I come from has a set voicemail greeting length of *3 minutes*. Not sure what you're carrier has set a limit for voicemail greetings.

Answer (score 0):

This is not generally something that Apple supports. However when you backup your phone to your computer the voicemails are (usually) saved in the backup.

There are programs out there that let you open up an iPhone backup and extract the contents, including voicemail files.

I will leave the discovery of these *iPhone Explorer* utilities between you and your favorite search engine.